# Excel - Copy specified columns to a new sheet based on data in a column

Tags: vba, excel, copy, autofilter

I require assistance with the following please:

I need to filter a Range A9 - A32 for any data in column G.
Then i need to copy the data, but only columns A - E & G to sheet 2.
then delete the filtered data and return back to non filtered view.

I have tried the following without success:

```
Dim shSrc As Worksheet
Dim shDst As Worksheet
Dim rSrc As range
Dim rDst As range
Dim range
Dim numCol As Long ' number of columns to copy

On Error GoTo EH

range = ("A:E,G:G")

' select source and dest sheets
Set shSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Active Snag List")
Set shDst = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Snag History")

' Select initial rows
Set rSrc = shSrc.Cells(9, 7)
Set rDst = shDst.Cells(2, 1)

' loop over source
Do While rSrc <> ""
    ' Test Source row, Qty = 0 and Name is not blank
    With rSrc
        If .Offset(0, 2) = 0 And .Value <> "" Then
            'Copy
            .Resize(1, range).Copy rDst.Resize(1, range)
            Set rDst = rDst.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
    Set rSrc = rSrc.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Exit Sub
EH:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Description
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `then delete the filtered data and return back to non filtered view.` do your mean delete the rows, or remove the filter (you arn't actually using a filter in the popsted code)

Answer (score 0):

To get your code working , replace the `IF` section with this

```
        If .Offset(0, 2) = 0 And .Value <> "" Then
            'Copy
            'Cells A:E
            rDst.Resize(1, 5).Value = .EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value
            ' Cell G
            rDst.Offset(0, 6).Value = .Value

            Set rDst = rDst.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Autofilter rather than looping through cells? It will me much faster. See this example.

**CODE(TRIED AND TESTED)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shDst As Worksheet
    Dim rDst As range, rng As range, rngtocopy As range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    On Error GoTo EH

    '~~> Select source and dest sheets
    Set shSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Active Snag List")
    Set shDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Snag History")

    '~~> Select initial rows
    Set rDst = shDst.Cells(2, 1)

    With shSrc
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Get the last row of Col G
        lastrow = .range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .range("A8:G" & lastrow)
            '~~> Filter G Col for non blanks
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>"
            '~~> Get the offset(to exclude headers)
            Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            '~~> Remove Col F from the resulting range
            Set rngtocopy = Union(shSrc.range(Replace(rng.Address, "G", "E")), _
            shSrc.range(Replace(rng.Address, "A", "G")))
            '~~> Copy cells to relevant destination
            rngtocopy.Copy rDst
            '~~> Delete the filtered results
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOTS**

Sheet 1 before the macro runs

[image]

Sheet 2 after the macro runs

[image]

Sheet 1 after the macro runs

[image]

Comment: Thank you much for all your effort! I appreciate it!

Comment: How can i edit the code to find the first empty row in sheet2 and paste the data? thanks

Comment: Replace `Set rDst = shDst.Cells(2, 1)` by `Set rDst = shDst.Range("A" & shDst.Range("A" & shDst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: If you substitute the range("A".... with ("A2") then the data is entered in row 20??? If you leave it as is then the data is written in row 1 which is the heading...thanks

Comment: Oops my mistake. Apologies. Use this `Set rDst = shDst.Range("A" & shDst.Range("A" & shDst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1)`